# sqlite query to get all list of table names with number of records in it

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite

Please help on below query :
sqlite query to get all list of table names with number of records in it :

I want to get the count of rows in every table in a Sqlite3 database. I want to avoid writing out a longhand query. I can get the list of tables like this:

SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'
and I would like to use it in a subquery like this:

select count (*) from (SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table');
but would just return the total rows in the subquery, which isn't what I want.

Comment: Since table names have to be known when the query is being prepared, you have to do it in steps. Get a list of table names and loop over that running one query per table, inserting the table name into a query string each time.

Comment: yes, getting the data in loop is one way . i was looking for single query that will the resulted data . If some inner joins can be done on "sqlite_master"

Comment: You can't do it in a single query.

Comment: thanks ..I Will update if get some work around

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you use the results of [`ANALYZE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) to create a workaround. It creates the internal schema object [`sqlite_stat1`](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#intschema)

> **2.6.3. The sqlite_stat1 table**
>
> The sqlite_stat1 is an internal table created by the ANALYZE command
>   and used to hold supplemental information about tables and indexes
>   that the query planner can use to help it find better ways of
>   performing queries. Applications can update, delete from, insert into
>   or drop the sqlite_stat1 table, but may not create or alter the
>   sqlite_stat1 table. The schema of the sqlite_stat1 table is as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE sqlite_stat1(tbl,idx,stat);
> ```
>
> There is normally one row per index, with the index identified by the
>   name in the sqlite_stat1.idx column. The sqlite_stat1.tbl column is
>   the name of the table to which the index belongs. In each such row,
>   the sqlite_stat.stat column will be a string consisting of a list of
>   integers followed by zero or more arguments. The first integer in this
>   list is the approximate number of rows in the index. (The number of
>   rows in the index is the same as the number of rows in the table,
>   except for partial indexes.) .....

If there are no partial indexes, the `SELECT tbl,cast(stat as INT)` will return the number of rows in each table, unless the table has 0 rows.

This sql gives the expected results on a small (25MB, 34 tables, 26 indexes, 33K+ rows) production database. Your mileage may (will?) vary.

```
ANALYZE;
select  DISTINCT tbl_name, CASE WHEN stat is null then 0 else cast(stat as INT) END numrows 
from sqlite_master m 
LEFT JOIN sqlite_stat1 stat on   m.tbl_name = stat.tbl 
where m.type='table'
and m.tbl_name not like 'sqlite_%'
order by 1;
--drop table sqlite_stat1;
```